# Git commit branches after changing origin

Tags: git, github

I have clone cef repo as:

`git clone https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef.git`

And it has several branches too, which can be checked by running

```
> git branch -a
* (HEAD detached at origin/3202)
  master
  remotes/origin/3202
  remotes/origin/3239
```

Now I want to commit this repo to my own git repo by changing the remote URL as:

```
>git remote set-url origin git@github.com:g-jha/cef.git
>git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:g-jha/cef.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:g-jha/cef.git (push)
> git push -u origin master
> git push -u origin origin/3202
```

But I only see master branch in my repo. branch `3202` cannot be seen in drop down.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following link helped me:
https://github.com/aiidateam/aiida_core/wiki/How-to-migrate-from-BitBucket-to-GitHub

I just needed to clone and push the repo with `--mirror` option.

```
>git clone --mirror https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef.git
>cd cef.git
>git remote set-url --push origin git@github.com:g-jha/cef.git
>git remote -v
origin  https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:g-jha/cef.git (push)

>git push --mirror
```